# Complement naive bayes

Tags: machine-learning, multinomial-distribution, bayes

I would like some help in understanding how does Complement Naive Bayes work. I have googled the paper [Complement Naive Bayes](http://people.csail.mit.edu/jrennie/papers/icml03-nb.pdf)

I understand that naive bayes works by computing the probability of a document belonging to a class based on its features. However, in complement naive bayes it takes the complement of  features in other classes? I am unsure of this part as to how it works.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let's make this simple, and do a **very contrived** two class case:

Let's say we have three documents with the following words:

**Doc 1: "Food" occurs twice, "Meat" occurs once, "Brain" occurs once**

**Class of Doc 1: "Health"**

**Doc 2: "Food" occurs once, "Meat" occurs once, "Kitchen" occurs 9 times, "Job" occurs 5 times.**

**Class of Doc 2: "Butcher"**

**Doc 3: "Food" occurs 2 times, "Meat" occurs 1 times, "Job" occurs once.**

**Class of Doc 3: "Health"**

Total word count in class 'Health' - $(2 + 1 + 1) + (2 + 1 + 1) = 8$

Total word count in class 'Butcher' - $(1 + 1 + 9 + 5) = 16$

So we have two possible y classes: $(y = Health)$ and $(y = Butcher)$, with prior probabilities thus:

$p(y = Health) = {2 \over 3}$ (2 out of 3 docs are about health)

$p(y = Butcher) = {1 \over 3}$

Now, for **Complement** Normal Naive Bayes, instead of calculating the likelihood of a word occuring in a class, we calculate the likelihood that it occurs **in other classes**. So, we would proceed to calculate the word-class dependencies thus:

Complement Probability of word 'Food' with class 'Health':
$$p(w = Food | \hat y = Health) = {1 \over 16}$$
See? 'Food' occurs 1 time in total for all classes NOT health, and the number of words in class NOT health is 16

Complement Probability of word 'Food' with class 'Butcher':
$$p(w = Food | \hat y = Butcher) = {2+1+5 \over 8} = 1 $$

For others,
$$p(w = Kitchen | \hat y = Health) = {9 \over 16}$$
$$p(w = Kitchen | \hat y = Butcher) = {0 \over 8} = 0$$
$$p(w = Meat | \hat y = Health) = {1 \over 16}$$
$$p(w = Meat | \hat y = Butcher) = {2 \over 8}$$

...and so forth

Then, say we had a new document containing the following:

**New doc: "Food" - 1, "Job" - 1, "Meat" - 1**

For normal Naive Bayes, (neglecting the constant evidence denominator), we would do our calculation and find the one with the maximum argument, viz:

$$argmax \ p(y) \bullet \prod p(w | y)^{f_i}$$

where $f_i$ is the frequency count of word $i$ in document $d$

But for Complement Naive Bayes, we would do:

$$argmin \ p(y) \bullet \prod {1 \over p(w | \hat y)^{f_i}}$$

*...and now seek the one with the **minimum** argument.*

We would predict the class of this new doc by doing the following:

$$ p(y=Health|w_1 = Food, w_2 =Job, w_3 =Meat) = $$
which gives us
$$ p(y=Health) \bullet {1 \over p(w = Food | \hat y=Health)^{f_{Food}} \bullet p(w = Job | \hat y=Health)^{f_{Butcher}} \bullet p(w=Meat|\hat y=Health)^{f_{Meat}}} $$

Let's work it out - this will give us:

$$ {2 \over 3} \bullet {1 \over { {1 \over 16}^{1} \bullet {5 \over 16}^{1} \bullet {1 \over 16}^{1} } } \approx 6.302 $$

and for the second:

$$ p(y=Butcher) \bullet {1 \over p(w = Food | \hat y=Butcher)^{f_{Food}} \bullet p(w = Job | \hat y=Butcher)^{f_{Butcher}} \bullet p(w=Meat|\hat y=Butcher)^{f_{Meat}}} $$

giving us:

$$ {1 \over 3} \bullet {1 \over { {1 \over 8}^{1} \bullet {1 \over 8}^{1} \bullet {2 \over 8}^{1} } } \approx 85.333 $$

...and likewise for the other classes. So, the one with the lower probability (minimum value) is said to be the class it belongs to - in this case, our new doc will be classified as belonging to **Health**. We DON'T use the one with the maximum probability because for the Complement Naive Bayes Algorithm, we take it - a higher value - to mean that *it is highly likely that a document with these words does **NOT** belong to that class*.

Obviously, this example is, again, highly contrived, and we should even talk about Laplacian smoothing. But hope this helps you have a working idea on which you can build!

Comment: awesome simply awesome answer. i wish everyone were answering like this

Comment: Say Knife occures a lot in documents with class Butcher, and rarely in documents with class health and both classes have approx. same number of total words.

Hence, complement probability P(knife/y=Butcher) = "a low value"

complement probability P(knife/y=Health) = "a high value"
New document with "knife" will have P(health/d) = low value, while P(Butcher/d) a high value. Taking argmin will classify the document as Health, which wont be correct, I guess

Comment: An attempted editor argues that the numerator of p(food|butcher) should be 2+2.